# Why in the UK would a garden room have a canopy?

Tags: outdoor, design

I'm putting a gym and art / craft rooms in the garden for the kids to mess around without making a mess in the house.  Typical garden rooms seen on architecture sites have patio doors, French doors or bifold doors in order to connect with the garden, and have a canopy over [like these](https://www.iqglassuk.com/projects/slim-framed-sliding-glass-doors-mw-garden-rooms/s15215/), then a patio outside.

Why would a garden room in the UK have a canopy?  And when would it be better to build one with, or without a canopy?

Comment: @isherwood maybe it's loading now?  Garden room = posh shed.

Answer (score 3):

To keep rain and dirt off the glass an to offer a bit of shade?

We have an Orangery with a wide cornice around the roof. It does a good job of sheltering the windows.

It also stops a square. flat roffed building looking like a bunker.

Our Orangery look crap until the cornice went on. Then it looked epic!